# Convert string value to Timestamp - PySparkSQL

Tags: apache-spark-sql

I need to convert a date string e.g. `2022-04-12T14:22:34Z` to timestamp in PySpark/SparkSQL before loading it to a Postgres table.

I have tried `SELECT TO_TIMESTAMP(REGEXP_REPLACE('2022-04-12T14:22:34Z', '[TZ]', ''), 'YYYY-MM-DDHH:MM:SS') AS result`

It works somewhat, but just wondering if there is an elegant way to accomplish the same in Spark 2.4.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this:

```
df.withColumn("date", to_timestamp(col("date"), "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss'Z'"))
```

Input:

```
+--------------------+
|                date|
+--------------------+
|2022-04-12T14:22:34Z|
+--------------------+
```

Output:

```
+-------------------+
|date               |
+-------------------+
|2022-04-12 14:22:34|
+-------------------+
```

Good luck!

Comment: thank you so much @vilalabinot. This works great ! However, just checking if the same is achievable thru Spark SQL ? - spark.sql("SELECT ....")

Comment: If `main` is your table, then: `spark.sql("select *, to_timestamp(date, \"yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss'Z'\") as date2 from main")` gives the same result. Please, mark the answer as resolved for future reference